# remove duplicate line from mysql-slow.log file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, awk, sed, grep

I have file whose name is mysql-slow.log.

I want to remove duplicate query.

search line is **SELECT accounts.*,accounts_cstm.* FROM accounts  LEFT JOIN accounts_cstm ON accounts.id = accounts_cstm.id_c  WHERE customer_id_c = '' AND deleted=0 LIMIT 0,1;**

Below is sample file

```
# Time: 180110 11:31:06
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]
# Query_time: 2.224965  Lock_time: 0.000052 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 92610
SET timestamp=1515564066;
SELECT b_invoice.*,b_invoice_cstm.* FROM b_invoice  LEFT JOIN b_invoice_cstm ON b_invoice.id = b_invoice_cstm.id_c  WHERE order_id_c = '212959' AND deleted=0 LIMIT 0,1;
# Time: 180110 11:38:12
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]
# Query_time: 2.041713  Lock_time: 0.000048 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 101355
SET timestamp=1515564492;
SELECT accounts.*,accounts_cstm.* FROM accounts  LEFT JOIN accounts_cstm ON accounts.id = accounts_cstm.id_c  WHERE customer_id_c = '' AND deleted=0 LIMIT 0,1;
# Time: 180110 11:39:02
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]
# Query_time: 2.124880  Lock_time: 0.000037 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 101355
SET timestamp=1515564542;
SELECT accounts.*,accounts_cstm.* FROM accounts  LEFT JOIN accounts_cstm ON accounts.id = accounts_cstm.id_c  WHERE customer_id_c = '' AND deleted=0 LIMIT 0,1;
# Time: 180110 11:39:18
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]
# Query_time: 2.016269  Lock_time: 0.000026 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 101355
SET timestamp=1515564558;
SELECT accounts.*,accounts_cstm.* FROM accounts  LEFT JOIN accounts_cstm ON accounts.id = accounts_cstm.id_c  WHERE customer_id_c = '' AND deleted=0 LIMIT 0,1;
# Time: 180110 11:40:11
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]
# Query_time: 2.261057  Lock_time: 0.000040 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 101355
SET timestamp=1515564611;
SELECT accounts.*,accounts_cstm.* FROM accounts  LEFT JOIN accounts_cstm ON accounts.id = accounts_cstm.id_c  WHERE customer_id_c = '' AND deleted=0 LIMIT 0,1;
# Time: 180110 11:40:13
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]
# Query_time: 2.862533  Lock_time: 0.000050 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 101355
SET timestamp=1515564613;
SELECT accounts.*,accounts_cstm.* FROM accounts  LEFT JOIN accounts_cstm ON accounts.id = accounts_cstm.id_c  WHERE customer_id_c = '' AND deleted=0 LIMIT 0,1;
```

And output file should be

```
#Time: 180110 11:31:06
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]
# Query_time: 2.224965  Lock_time: 0.000052 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 92610
SET timestamp=1515564066;
SELECT b_invoice.*,b_invoice_cstm.* FROM b_invoice  LEFT JOIN b_invoice_cstm ON b_invoice.id = b_invoice_cstm.id_c  WHERE order_id_c = '212959' AND deleted=0 LIMIT 0,1;
# Time: 180110 11:38:12
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]
# Query_time: 2.041713  Lock_time: 0.000048 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 101355
SET timestamp=1515564492;
SELECT accounts.*,accounts_cstm.* FROM accounts  LEFT JOIN accounts_cstm ON accounts.id = accounts_cstm.id_c  WHERE customer_id_c = '' AND deleted=0 LIMIT 0,1;
```

**Note :** Also remove Upper 3 line before query

```
#Time
#User
#Query_time
```

mysql command to delete single line is

```
sudo sed -i '/^SELECT accounts.*,accounts_cstm.* FROM accounts  LEFT JOIN accounts_cstm ON accounts.id = accounts_cstm.id_c  WHERE customer_id_c = '' AND deleted=0 LIMIT 0,1;/d' mysql-slow.log
```

Answer (score 0):

This one might help you :)

```
awk '/^SET/{ s = $0; next }/^SELECT/&& !(a[$0]++){ print s; print $0 }' infile
```

Output:

```
SET timestamp=1515564066;
SELECT b_invoice.*,b_invoice_cstm.* FROM b_invoice  LEFT JOIN b_invoice_cstm ON b_invoice.id = b_invoice_cstm.id_c  WHERE order_id_c = '212959' AND deleted=0 LIMIT 0,1;
SET timestamp=1515564492;
SELECT accounts.*,accounts_cstm.* FROM accounts  LEFT JOIN accounts_cstm ON accounts.id = accounts_cstm.id_c  WHERE customer_id_c = '' AND deleted=0 LIMIT 0,1;
```

The first part `/^SET/{ s = $0; next }` looks for each line that starts with SET. When a line starts with set the whole line ($0) is stored in the variable s. The second part `/^SELECT/&& !(a[$0]++){ print s; print $0 }'` is looking for lines that start with SELECT and are not in the array a. If a line is not in the a it will be added and the variable s and the the whole line starting with SELECT will be printed.

Comment: what to do for order_id_c = '212959' and order_id_c = '212960' in this query is same only order_id_c  field value is changed

Comment: So, you mean if the order_id_c changes but the query will remain the same? With my solution it will be printed. If you don't want that you should edit your question with a example for that or open a new one. Until now my answer solves what you asked for in your question.

Comment: You can strip those values from your input file with a regular expression such as `cat infile | sed -e "s/order_id_c = '.*'/order_id_c = 'SANITIZED'/"`

In addition you can also look at the tool pt-query-digest from https://www.percona.com/software/database-tools/percona-toolkit